# Do not index certain pages on Google Search

Tags: wordpress, google-search, robots.txt

Is it possible to not index certain pages on Google Search?

I'm using WordPress. I've heard a robots.txt can prevent bots from crawling your website, but is this the same as indexing? Is it even possible at all?

Comment: You can add `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">` in your needed page inside `<head>` tag if you do wish bots to index those pages.

Comment: Do you really need a solution only for Google Search, not affecting other search engine services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org/)
>
> Web Robots (also known as Web Wanderers, Crawlers, or Spiders), are
>   programs that traverse the Web automatically. Search engines such as
>   Google use them to index the web content, spammers use them to scan
>   for email addresses, and they have many other uses.

To exclude all robots from the entire server

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

To exclude all robots from part of the server

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /junk/
```

Comment: robots.txt prevents crawling, not necessarily indexing.